# Git push error: remote: error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database ./objects

Tags: git, apache

I have been struggling with setup Git under apache on Redhat for many days.

- Apache version: erver version: Apache/2.4.6 (Red Hat Enterprise
  Linux)
- Git version 1.8.3.1
- Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.1 Beta
- Configuration for Git under apache:

> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>         SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /var/www/git
>         SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
>         ScriptAlias /git/ /usr/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend/
>
> <Directory "/usr/libexec/git-core*">
>    Options ExecCGI Indexes
>    Order allow,deny
>    Allow from all
>    Require all granted
> </Directory>
>
> <LocationMatch "^/git/.*/git-receive-pack$">
>     AuthType Basic
>     AuthName "Git Access"
>     AuthUserFile /var/www/passwd.git
>     Require valid-user
> </LocationMatch>
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

- on the server site I did

> ```
> mkdir  /var/www/test1
> cd /var/www/git/test1
>
> # init repo
> git init --bare
> touch git-daemon-export-ok
> cp hooks/post-update.sample hooks/post-update
> git config http.receivepack true
> git config core.sharedRepository group
> git update-server-info
>
> chown -R apache:apache .
> chmod -R 775 .
> ```

- And Git config file on server as below

> ```
> [core]
>         repositoryformatversion = 0
>         filemode = true
>         bare = true
>         sharedRepository = group
> [http]
>         receivepack = true
> ```

After I clone the bare service repository /var/www/git/test1 as

> git clone http://192.168.26.129/git/test1

When I push any change from client, I still get the error as

> ```
> $ git push origin master
> Counting objects: 3, done.
> Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 202 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
> Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
> Username for 'http://192.168.26.129': briangit
> remote: error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database ./objects
> remote: fatal: failed to write object
> error: unpack failed: unpack-objects abnormal exit
> To http://192.168.26.129/git/test1
>  ! [remote rejected] master -> master (unpacker error)
> error: failed to push some refs to 'http://192.168.26.129/git/test1'
> ```

I did many research online  and every possible try.
I really don't know what the problem is. Please help.

Comment: is it bare (empty) repo?

Answer (score 0):

**I suggest you to check the file permission.**

Check the file permission of ssh key, you can change it using chmod.
You changed the permissions on the whole directory, which I agree with Splash is a bad idea.

If you can remember what the original permissions for the directory are, I would try to set them back to that and then do the following

```
cd ~/.ssh
chmod 700 id_rsa
```

or

```
chmod 400 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

or

```
chmod 777 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

**CHMOD permission:**

```
#   Permission  rwx
7   read, write and execute rwx
6   read and write  rw-
5   read and execute    r-x
4   read only   r--
3   write and execute   -wx
2   write only  -w-
1   execute only    --x
0   none    ---
```

**Where you can find the key?**

side the .ssh folder. That will set the id_rsa file to rwx (read, write, execute) for the owner (you) only, and zero access for everyone else.

If above all didn't help, try to see your group. Add the user to group and try to push your branch to remote origin/master.

Comment: well ur just using different protocol, that is http.. that isn't the problem here. Only problem I faced with http is checking in the file with size of 4gb impossible. I prefer to use ssh.  Well its worth to check it out. you have changed the owner and permission to files.

Comment: Thanks, 

I am using the smart http instead of ssh for git, not sure http has anything to do with rsa.  the owner 'apache' of repository on server and client 'briangit' are in the same 'apache' group.

Comment: perhaps check the user is added to the group so that he/she can pull or push the branch to remote?

Comment: my repository is empty bare repo. It should not have problem with file size.

Comment: It's nothing to do with size . That's what I commented this bare repo that's why ur getting this problem. You just need to check the privileges of ssh key in your client that is your machine and check the user group. Have you tried above mentioned commands?

Answer (score 0):

Note: I have not touched Apache in 10+ years, so take this with as many grains of salt as required.  There is, though, one obvious problem:

> ```
> chmod -R 755 .
> ```

Don't do that (at all).  You should not have to.  Instead of:

> ```
> git init --bare
> git config core.sharedRepository group
> ```

use the one line sequence:

```
git init --bare --shared=group
```

(or just `--shared` which means the same thing).

It's not clear to me when and why you might want `http.receivepack` configured to `true`, but see [Documentation/git-http-backend.txt](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/git-http-backend.txt).

Comment: Thanks Torek,
It turns out the SELinux is culprit for this error. After it is disabled, It works fine.

Comment: Ah, SELinux. I was never able to get Git servers to work under that myself.

Comment: @briantalk would be useful if you wrote it to your OP, so this useful info is not hidden in the comment. Although for me it haven't solved my problem.